# this.http.post request returns 403 error

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a `http.post` request. I am trying to send some data through the url. It works with jmeter. But is not working in the application. It gives 403 error with "angular.js:13424 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

```
scheduledMeetings : function(sessionId, arg, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, SuccessCallback, ErrorCallback){
    if(sessionId ){
        var config = {headers: {
                'authorization': sessionId,
                'accept': 'application/json'    
            }
        };

        this.http.post(
            bcs_config.api_url+'/partner/scheduling/srfsearchbycustomer?customerId='+arg+'&timeZoneId='+arg1+
            '&startDate='+arg2+'&endDate='+arg3+'&meetsStatus='+arg4,
            config).success(SuccessCallback).error(ErrorCallback);

    }else{
        console.error("AHelper.js - Call scheduledMeetings() failed:"," sessionId is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: do a console.log of "bcs_config.api_url+'/partner/scheduling/srfsearchbycustomer?customerId='+arg+'&timeZoneId='+arg1+
            '&startDate='+arg2+'&endDate='+arg3+'&meetsStatus='+arg4" and check the Url. Also check angularJS documentation, you are sending the data via Get not Post, use a  comma after the URL. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: I used the same url in jmeter and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you missing a coma for data?

Comment: I need the args to be passed in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sending data, use GET instead of POST. If you want to use post without any data change  your code with:

```
  this.http.post(
            bcs_config.api_url+'/partner/scheduling/srfsearchbycustomer?customerId='+arg+'&timeZoneId='+arg1+
            '&startDate='+arg2+'&endDate='+arg3+'&meetsStatus='+arg4,null,
            config).success(SuccessCallback).error(ErrorCallback);
```

check the documentation, you miss one comma for data:

```
 $http.post(url, data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            });
```

Comment: it's the http post succes? perhaps it's on your callback function.

Comment: well, it didn't give the same error but because I am passing null data. I am receiving null output.